# Invocation timed out using Sagemaker to invoke endpoints with pretrained custom PyTorch model [Inference]

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I have a pretrained model based on PyTorch (contextualized_topic_models) and have deployed it using AWS sagemaker script model. However, when I tried to invoke endpoints for inference, it always returns "Invocation timed out error" no matter what I tried. I have tried different types of input and changing the input_fn() function but still it doesn't work.

I've tried to run my inference.py script on Colab (without connecting to the aws server) and each function seems to work perfectly fine with expected predictions returned.

I've been trying to debug this for 4 days now and even in my dream I thought about this issue... I'll be deeply grateful for any help.

Here's my deployment script.

```
from sagemaker.pytorch.model import PyTorchModel

pytorch_model = PyTorchModel(
    model_data=pretrained_model_data,
    entry_point="inference.py",
    role=role,
    framework_version="1.8.1",
    py_version="py36",
    sagemaker_session=sess,
)

endpoint_name = "topic-modeling-inference"

# Deploy
predictor = pytorch_model.deploy(
initial_instance_count = 1,
instance_type = "ml.g4dn.xlarge",
endpoint_name = endpoint_name
)
```

Endpoint test (prediction) script

```
# Test the model
import json
sm = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')
endpoint_name = "topic-modeling-inference"

prompt = [
    "Here is a piece of cake."
        ]

promptbody = [x.encode('utf-8') for x in prompt]
promptbody = promptbody[0]
#body= bytes(prompt[0], 'utf-8')
#tryout = prompt[0]


response = sm.invoke_endpoint(
EndpointName=endpoint_name,
ContentType="text/csv",
Body=promptbody 
#Body=tryout.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
)

print(response)

#result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
#print(result)
```

Part of my inference.py script

```
def predict_fn(input_data, model):
    input_data_features = tp10.transform(text_for_contextual=input_data)
    topic_prediction = model.get_doc_topic_distribution(input_data_features, n_samples=20)
    topicID = np.argmax(topic_prediction)
    topicID = int(topicID.astype('str'))
    return topicID
    #prediction = model.get_topic_lists(20)[np.argmax(topic_prediction)]
    #return prediction

def input_fn(request_body, request_content_type):
    if request_content_type == "application/json":
        request = json.loads(request_body)
    else:
        request = request_body
    return request

def output_fn(prediction, response_content_type):
    if response_content_type == "application/json":
        response = str(json.dumps(prediction))
    else:
        response = str(json.dumps(prediction))
    return response
```

Any help or guidance will be wonderful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Hi @ClockSlave, sorry I didn't check the notification here and got no email about your comment. Anyway, I was able to fix it but unfortunately forgot how I fixed the problem... Sorry I can't be of more help. You might find the comment from CrzyFella helpful.

Comment: Hey, no worries. The solution here didn't help but I figured it out.

Comment: @ClockSlave did you happen to remember how you fixed it? :D

Comment: hey @smcjones, i think i added a `model_fn` to make it work. If you haven't solved it, I can share the inference file with you

Comment: @smcjones, here you go. hope this helps https://pastebin.com/JM4HJPiq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to look into the CloudWatch logs of the endpoint to see if there are any invocations reaching the endpoint.

If yes, see if they are sending a response back without any errors in the same log file.